# How could I get a result for every column after comparing dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have two csv files, and the two files have the exact same amount of rows and columns containing only numerical values. I want to compare each columns separately.

The idea would be to compare column 1 value of file "a" to column 1 value of file "b" and check the difference and so on for all the numbers in the column (there are 100 rows) and write out a number that in how many cases were the difference more than 0. So e.g. if in the case of column 1 there where 55 numbers that didnt mach in case of file "a" and "b" than I want to get back a value of 55 for column 1 and so on.

I would like to repeat the same for all the columns. I know it should be a double for loop but idk exactly how.
Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd

dk = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/D/1_top_a.csv', sep=',', header=None)
dk = dk.dropna(how='all')
dk = dk.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
print(dk)

dl = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/D/1_top_b.csv', sep=',', header=None)
dl = dl.dropna(how='all')
dl = dl.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
#print(dl)

rows=dk.shape[0]
print(rows)

for row in range(len(dl)):
    for col in range(len(dl.columns)):
        if dl.iloc[row, col] != dk.iloc[row, col]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the recordlinkage package very useful for comparing values from 2 datasets. You can define which columns to compare and it returns a 0 or 1 if they match. Next, you can filter for all matching values

https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about.html

---

Code looks like this:

```
# create pair of dataframes to compare
indexer = rl.Index()
indexer.add(Block('row_identifier1', 'row_identifier2'))
datasets = indexer.index(dataset1, dataset2)

# initialise class
comparer = rl.Compare()

# initialise similarity measurement algorithms
comparer.string('string_value1', 'string_value2', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.95, label='string_matching')
comparer.exact('value3', 'value4', label='integer_matching')

# the method .compute() returns the DataFrame with the feature vectors.
results = comparer.compute(datasets, dataset1, dataset2)
```